# Pass data from parent to child angular.js components

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have parent component:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('app.module')
    .component('parentComponent', {
      templateUrl: 'parent.html',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      controller: function ($scope) {
      this.$onInit = () => {
        $scope.parentData = 'test'
      }
  })
})()
```

child component

```
(function () {
  angular.module('app.module').component('childComponent', {
  templateUrl: 'child.html',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  controller: function () {
  this.$onInit = () => {
  }
 }
})
})()
```

parent.html

```
<child-component></child-component>
```

child.html

```
<p>{{parentData}}</p>
```

So I want to have access to parentData in my child component for display string 'test' in my child component. How can I do it? I read something about bindings but I don't know how to use it in this example.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use one-way `<` binding:

```
<child-component in-data="$ctrl.parentData"></child-component>
```

The child component:

```
app.component("childComponent", {
    bindings: {
        inData: '<',
    },
    template: `
        <div>{{$ctrl.inData}}</div>
    `,
})
```

The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.component("parentComponent", {
    template: `
        <fieldset>
            Inside parent component<br>
            parentData={{$ctrl.parentData}}
            <child-component in-data="$ctrl.parentData"></child-component>
        </fieldset>
    `,
    controller: function () {
        this.$onInit = () => {
            this.parentData = 'test'
        };
    },
})
.component("childComponent",{
    bindings: {
        inData: '<',
    },
    template: `
        <fieldset>Inside child component<br>
            inData={{$ctrl.inData}}
        </fieldset>
    `,
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <parent-component>
    </parent-component>
<body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Comment: Great, it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can access parent's data via the parent controller, for that you can use [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) in your component declaration:

Here is an example:

```
app.component('childComponent', {
  require: {
    parentCtrl: '^parentComponent'
  },
  controller: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$onInit = function() {
      self.parentCtrl.anyData;
    };
  }
});
```

Take a look at [codelord.net - Advanced Angular 1.x: Component Communication with Require](https://www.codelord.net/2016/11/30/advanced-angular-1-dot-x-component-communication-with-require/)

If you don't need the parent controller you can bind data to your child component: refer to [@georgeawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535245/georgeawg) answer

Comment: If you are down voting please leave a message, so I can at least now why my answer is bad.
If it's because he asks for pass data from parent to child and my answer is to pass the controller I don't think it should be done voted. sometimes it helps to pass the controller and not only the data

Comment: The `require` technique should not be used to replace any kind of simple binding. It’s totally fine to pass some values between components using bindings–it can be more explicit and simpler to maintain. After all, it’s usually easier to understand what a component depends on if all you need to do is look at its bindings.

Comment: First and foremost, require doesn’t work in all scenarios. It can only be used by a component/directive to get access to a parent controller (or a controller on the same element). Sibling components can’t communicate using it, and neither can a parent component access its children using it (at least not directly, keep reading for an interesting option).

Comment: Another limitation of require is that it assumes the child component knows the name of the other component that it want to require. There’s no abstraction/indirection here – the name of the required component is hard-coded in the requiring component.

Comment: anyway I don't think it's fair-play to down vote my answer. Maybe it's not a best practice and may be better to bind data to child. But if the require attribute exists and angular makes it possible so is not so bad to do it like this.

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer